# $firebaseSimpleLoginProvider not found

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I'm having trouble getting the facebookSimpleLogin angularfire service to be dependency injected into one of my angular js services.

```
angular.module('cakethursdayApp')
.service('FacebookAuthService', function FacebookAuthService($firebaseSimpleLogin) {
    ......
});
```

I am getting the error "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $firebaseSimpleLoginProvider <- $firebaseSimpleLogin <- FacebookAuthService"

I have my scripts loaded in the following order

```
<script src="bower_components/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/firebase-simple-login/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angularfire/angularfire.js"></script>
```

Comment: have you enabled facebook login in forge?  it's under the simple login section on the dashboard.

Comment: Make sure you have newer versions of JS files (firebase-simple-login.js didn't have $firebaseSimpleLoginProvider 6 months ago) https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#getting-started

Comment: You also need to include the `firebase` dependency where your module is first declared: `angular.module('cakethursdayApp', ['firebase'])`.

Comment: @Kato thanks :) Seems obvious now! I was following the angularfire simple login introduction to the T and they unfortunately neglect that!

Comment: We're constantly working to improve the docs. I'll add that to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking when you have a "missing dependency" always take a look at your module declaration's dependency injection.

```
angular.module(modulename, [list of dependencies to inject]).
```

Anytime you're using firebase (with angularfire I know specifically) you'll want something like this

```
angular.module(modulename, ['firebase'])
```

Additionally (often times you'll need it) in your controller definition as well.

```
function myCtrl($scope, $firebase)
```

This way when you want to setup a reference to your firebase URL it'll look like this:

```
var FB = "https://##instance##.firebaseio.com/"; //your Firebase address
var ref = new Firebase(FB);  // Creates a new instance of AngularFire 
$scope.variableNames= $firebase(ref); // the angularfire "firebase" service reference.
```

(please correct me if my comments are wrong up there, this is my understanding of the code)

for use in ng-repeat or other operations

```
(For Example)

<div ng-repeat="variable in variableNames">
{{variable}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two changes in current code to make it working:

```
angular.module('cakethursdayApp', ['firebase'])
.service('FacebookAuthService', function FacebookAuthService($firebaseAuth) {
    ......
});
```

1. Inject AngularFire module as dependency
2. Replace **$firebaseSimpleLogin** with **$firebaseAuth** because
   $firebaseSimpleLogin was dropped/removed in of 0.9.0.